# ajax work for 4 time onchange event after that it not generate response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ajax work for 4 time onchange event after that it not generate response

//this is function call when dropdownlist value is change

```
function doAjaxPost(instituteId) {
     alert(instituteId);
    // get the form values  
    /* var name = $('#name').val();
    var education = $('#education').val(); */
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "/paymentGateway/merchant",
        dataType : "json",
        data : "institutionId=" + instituteId,
        success : function(data) {
            // we have the response  
            alert(data + "hiee");
            var $merchantId = $('#merchant');
            $merchantId.find('option').remove();
            $("#merchant").append("<option value='ALL'>ALL</option>");
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                $('<option>').val(value.merchantId).text(value.merchantId)
                        .appendTo($merchantId);
            });

        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert('Error: ' + e);
        }
    });
}
```

//HTML code

```
<select name="institutionId" onchange="doAjaxPost(this.value)" id="instiuteId">
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<c:forEach var="institute" items="${instititionList}">
<option value="${institute.institutionId}">${institute.institutionId}</option>
</c:forEach>    
</select>
```

//this is dropdown which should be loaded whenever onchange event is occur on institutionid dropdown

```
<select name="merchantId" id="merchant">
<option value="ALL">ALL</option>
<c:forEach var="merchant" items="${merchantList}">
 <option value="${merchant.merchantId}">${merchant.merchantId}</option>
 </c:forEach>
 </select>
```

Comment: also post your html code. How you bind your dropdown onchange?

Comment: Are u using JSTL, JSP

Comment: yess i m using jstl jsp